# Destroy() does not work inside OnBecameInvisible()

Tags: unity

I'm trying to destroy an object when it's out of the camera's view.

My code works correctly on every object in the scene, but when I'm creating an object from a prefab using `Instantiate()`, it doesn't works!

### Here's Sv_Generator.cs

```
public class Sv_Generator : MonoBehaviour {
   public GameObject generator_proxy;
   public GameObject object_prefab;

    void Update () {
         GameObject new_object = (GameObject)Instantiate(object_prefab, generator_proxy.transform.position, generator_proxy.transform.rotation);
         new_object.name = (System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")).Substring(0, 6);
    }

    }
```

### Here's AutoDestroy.cs, which is attached to the prefab `object_prefab`

```
public class AutoDestroy : MonoBehaviour {


    void OnBecameInvisible()
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        Debug.Log(name + " is out!"); // This line prints!
    }

    void Update()
    {
       /// If I put Destroy(gameObject); here, it works!
    }

}
```

Now I start the game. When new objects go off-screen, `Debug.Log(name + " is out!");` fires and works as expected, but `Destroy(gameObject);` does not fire and nothing happens!

But if I put `Destroy(gameObject);` in  `void Update ()` it works :\

**I also tried :**

```
GameObject get_obj = GameObject.Find(name);
Destroy(get_obj);
```

No luck! :(

How can I make it work ?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this problem. In my tests, placing Destroy() inside OnBecameInvisible() works as expected, whenever OnBecameInvisible is called. I did note that the call does not happen in-editor if the object is still visible to the scene camera while the scene view is shown, even if it's out of view in-game. Can you produce a minimal, complete, verifiable example that we can test and reproduce in a new empty project?

Comment: Additionally, just because the debug line is called doesn't mean that`Destroy` didn't work: `Destroy` is not an immediate function and the object isn't actually removed until the end of frame.